# For a list of dates, check if it is between another list of 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to compare 2 lists of dates, by checking if the date in the first dataframe with column 'timekey' is between the 2 dates, where the 2 dates is the date in timelist and timelist - 1 year.

An example would be checking if 30Aug2020 is between 30Nov2020 and 30Nov2020-1year, I.E 30Nov2019.
I then want to have a 3rd column in the original df where it shows the difference between the timekey date and the compared timelist date.

I'm doing all of this in python using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

datelist = pd.date_range(start = dt.datetime(2016,8,31), end = dt.datetime(2020,11,30), freq = '3M')
data = {'ID': ['1', '2', '3'], 'timekey': ['31Dec2016', '30Jun2017', '30Aug2018']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timekey'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timekey'])

print(df)
print(datelist)
```

Here is the code I tried, but I have a value error where they say lengths must match to compare. Whats going on?

```
for date in datelist:
    if (df['timekey'] <= datelist) & (df['timekey'] >= (datelist - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1))):
        df['diff'] = df['timekey'] - (datelist - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1))
```

The expected output should be that for each timekey, if it is within the date range specified by the datelist, it should generate an entire new row with the same ID and timekey with the 3rd new column being the difference in months.

For example, if the timekey is 30Jun2020, it would be between 30Nov2019-30Nov2020, 30Aug2019-30Aug2020. There would be 2 rows created whereby the time difference in months would be 5 and 2 respectively.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: "for date in datelist" will iterate through the 18 dates in datelist. "df" only has 3 rows so it sounds/ looks like you're trying to add a column with 18 rows  to a df with only 3.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I could think of to solve your problem would be using the unix timestamp (which will return you the seconds passed since 1970-01-01) to compare. Therefore you would need to convert your dates to unix.
Something like this would work:

```
unixTime = (pd.to_datetime(<yourTime>) - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
```

so a working example to check if a date is in-between two dates could look like this:

```
def checkIfInbetween(date1,date2,dateToCheck):
   date1 = (pd.to_datetime(date1) - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')) //   pd.Timedelta('1s')
   date2 = (pd.to_datetime(date1) - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
   dateToCheck = (pd.to_datetime(dateToCheck) - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
      if(dateToCheck<date2 && dateToCheck>date1):
         return True
      else:
         return False

df['isInbetween'] = df.apply(lamdbda x: checkIfInbetween(x['date1'], x['date2'], x['dateToCheck']))
```

(Code not tested)